# Styling actionBar affects styling of Preferences

Tags: android, android-xml

When i add the following line to my themes.xml to hide the actionbar icon:

```
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

It is affecting my preferences activity styling.

Here is my settings.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Security" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:title="Enable Passcode Protection"
        android:summary="A 4 digit pin to protect all of your accounts."
        android:key="prefCodePasscode"
        android:defaultValue="false"/>
    <com.rcd.simpleregister.PasswordDialogPreference
        android:key="prefPasscode"
        android:title="Set Passcode"
        android:summary="Enable application passcode for enhanced security."
        android:positiveButtonText="Ok"
        android:negativeButtonText="Cancel"
        android:dependency="prefCodePasscode"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Its going from this (without the android:icon styling)
[image]

To this (with the android:icon styling)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `android:icon` from the style definition. Instead, for Activities which should not have the icon, set the `android:icon` attribute for those activities in their AndroidManifest elements:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:icon="@android:color/transparent" />
```